# Data Conversion with DatePart in an MS access select query

Tags: select, ms-access-2007, insert-into

I am trying to use DatePart() within a MS Access select query to extract a month and year-- as a number-- from a date which is initially in a string form of

---

"YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.0000000"

---

The initial code written by someone else says:

```
DatePart("m", date)
DatePart("yyyy", date)
```

But this was causing a "Data Type, Mismatch in Criteria" error when the query ran, so I attempted to use Cdate() to convert the string to a date type.

```
DatePart("m", Cdate(date))
DatePart("yyyy", Cdate(date))
```

However this did not solve the problem.  I am wondering if my initial date string is not in a form that Cdate() can convert, or if there is an easier way to extract a partial, numerical date from a date string such as mine.

I am prepared to elaborate much further on the situation in case this question is incomplete, but I did not wish get ahead of myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those extra zeros would be a problem, to strip them, you could say

```
CDate(Mid(sdate, 1, InStr(sdate, ".") - 1))
```

Then

```
DatePart("m", CDate(Mid(sdate, 1, InStr(sdate, ".") - 1)))
```

However, you may find it more convenient to just refer to the appropriate part of the string:

```
aYr = Left(sdate,4)
aMnth = Mid(sdate,6,2)
```

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to reply... This did get rid of the type mismatch error I was encountering.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You were right that the fractional seconds prevent `CDate` from accepting your string.  And you could strip away the fractional seconds.  But since you ultimately want the year and month, you can ignore all of the time components and just use the date part.

See whether this Immediate window session offers anything useful.

```vb
MyString = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss") & ".0000000"
? MyString
2013-02-14 23:38:09.0000000
' if date format is always yyyy-mm-dd,
' give CDate the first 10 characters
? CDate(Left(MyString, 10))
2/14/2013 
' year
? DatePart("yyyy", CDate(Left(MyString, 10)))
 2013 
' or
? Year(Left(MyString, 10))
 2013 
' month
? DatePart("m", CDate(Left(MyString, 10)))
 2 
' or
? Month(CDate(Left(MyString, 10)))
 2 

' if date format can vary slightly, eg yyyy-m-d,
' give CDate everything before the first space
? CDate(Left(MyString, InStr(MyString, Chr(32)) -1))
2/14/2013 
? Year(CDate(Left(MyString, InStr(MyString, Chr(32)) -1)))
 2013 
? Month(CDate(Left(MyString, InStr(MyString, Chr(32)) -1)))
 2
```

You didn't mention what you will do with the year and date numbers after you get them.  If you intend to join them together as a string, you could use `Format()`.

```vb
? Format(Left(MyString, 10), "yyyymm")
201302
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is also helpful information.  Essentially the problem has been solved: DatePart() needs an argument of type date, and CDate() needs a string argument without a trailing fractional seconds portion.

Comment: So are you saying that when extracting the date value from your string, you prefer `CDate(Mid(YourString, 1, InStr(YourString, ".") - 1))` over `CDate(Left(YourString, 10))`? 3 functions instead of 2?

Comment: No, calling Left() is more efficient in this situation, I agree.  But the concept of omitting a variable amount of fractional seconds might be more useful in general.  Also his promptness in answering helped me greatly :)